# Create column with only file name from Amazon S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a column `Fname` that contains the file names without extension, I'm using this code but it returns `*`:

```
import boto3 
import pandas as pd
import os 

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')    
bg = s3.Bucket("mybucket")
objects = bg.objects.filter(Prefix="myprefix")

file_list = []

for obj in objects:
 
   df = pd.read_excel('s3://mybucket/myprefix/*.xlsx',sheet_name='X')
   df['fname'] =  os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f's3://mybucket/myprefix/*.xlsx'))[0]
 
 file_list.append(df)
 final_df = pd.concat(file_list) 
 print(final_df)
```

However, the result is `fname column = *`

I inserted `*.xlsx` because I have a lot of files in this prefix, so I need to create a column with file name to each excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a wildcard, you should use the current value of the object from the `for` loop:

```py
for obj in objects:
 
   df = pd.read_excel(f's3://mybucket/{obj.key}',sheet_name='X')
   df['fname'] =  os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f's3://mybucket/{obj.key}'))[0]
```